# What's the difference between "cacheLast = 0/1/2" in TDengine's configuration file "taos.cfg"?

Tags: database, tdengine

There's an item "cacheLast" in TDengine's configuration file "taos.cfg", its value can be 0, 1, 2.
What's the difference between them? (cacheLast = 0/1/2)
Does it cache Time-Series data?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are 4 options for cachelast now

- 0. no cache;
- 1. cache result for query: `select last_row() from table`;
- 2. cache result for query: `select last() from table`;
- 3. cache result for both last_row() and last() query;